# raise error if table does not exists in database

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to handle error if any table is deleted from the database
situation is like -

```
ALTER procedure ABC as 
begin tran tansinsert
insert into table1 values (1,2,3)
if @@error <> 0
begin
rollback tran tansinsert
end
else
begin
commit tran tansinsert
end
```

if i am running this proc and table 'table1 ' was not in database than how i will get error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way

```
IF NOT  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[table1 ]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
       RAISERROR(......)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--rest of flow
END
GO
```

Comment: thanks for reply,yes I can check first that table exists or not , but in my case more than 30 tables are getting used in proc. is there any way I can catch exception if table is not there ,on compiling procedure  it compile fine but it does not roll-back transaction on @@error

Answer (score 1):

Sample code to catch error

```
BEGIN TRY
     EXECUTE Abc
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
     print 'Error got'
     SELECT 
          ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber,
          ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;
```

If you do the following this does not work.

```
CREATE PROC test
AS
BEGIN TRY
  SELECT * FROM NonexistentTable
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   -- some code
END CATCH
```

The only way this works is if you have one stored procedure call another stored procedure such as this:

```
CREATE PROC Test
AS
SELECT * FROM NonexistentTable
GO

CREATE PROC test2
AS
BEGIN TRY
  EXECUTE Test
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   -- some code
END CATCH
GO
```

TRY…CATCH constructs do not trap the following conditions:

1. Warnings or informational messages that have a severity of 10 or lower.
2. Errors that have a severity of 20 or higher that stop the SQL Server Database Engine task processing for the session. If an error occurs that has severity of 20 or higher and the database connection is not disrupted, TRY…CATCH will handle the error.
3. Attentions, such as client-interrupt requests or broken client connections.
4. When the session is ended by a system administrator by using the KILL statement.

The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:

1. Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running.
2. Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DBNAME..TABLENAME') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
//YOUR CODE FLOW HERE
END

ELSE
BEGIN
//RAISE ERROR HERE
END
GO
```